# My laptop still displays on the TV even if I turn the TV off

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, windows-11, asus-laptop, display-settings

When I connect my laptop to the LG tv via HDMI and choose display on screen 2 it works fine (laptop screen is off, desktop is on TV), but when I turn the TV off it continues that way and does not automatically switch to the laptop screen.
This issue happens for my windows 11 ASUS tuf dash f15 laptop, but not for my 12 year old HP Pavilion laptop which automatically switches to the laptop screen when I switch off the TV.
Why does this happen? Is there a solution for this issue?

Comment: might be the HDMI cable

Answer (score 1):

The GPU is not detecting the loss of connection with the TV.  This is something that *should* be detected and your older laptop is handling this properly.

This is likely a driver issue with your Asus' GPU.  Make sure you have the latest updates for your OS, BIOS/firmware updates for your Asus laptop, as well as the latest driver for the GPU.

Check Asus and your GPU's support forums for people having the same issue on that model.  Hopefully, there is a known solution or at least the bug has been reported.  If you have all the latest updates, there is not much else you can do, other than report this bug to Asus and the GPU manufacturer and hope they fix it.

Comment: It could also be the TV not telling the connected device it is turned off.

Comment: @music2myear could be, but the gpu should detect the loss of connectivity either way.